# TensorFlow : NotFoundError: Resource AnonymousIterator Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, anaconda, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to replicate the example of using RNN in time-series as posted on 
https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/time_series#multi-step_model

However, I am getting the following error message :

```
 NotFoundError: Resource AnonymousIterator/AnonymousIterator3/class 
 tensorflow::data::IteratorResource does not exist.
 [[{{node IteratorGetNext_3}}]]
```

When I trying to execute the line :

```
for x, y in val_univariate.take(1):
print(simple_lstm_model.predict(x,steps=1).shape)
```

Environment :

```
Tenserflow : 2.0.0-beta1
Python : Python 3.6.7 Anaconda
OS : Windows 10 64-bit
```

Any solutions for this?

Comment: I am experiencing smth similar when passing a dictionary of tensors to the predict method. Have you found a solution or filed an issue on git?

Comment: No I was not able to find the solution to this issue and subsequently had to revert back to older version. Can you submit the issue on git.

Comment: I also faced this kind of error while running [This Example](https://github.com/cerlymarco/MEDIUM_NoteBook/blob/master/Time2Vec/Time2Vec2.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

From [TF doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#__iter__),

It states:

> Creates an Iterator for enumerating the elements of this dataset.
>
> The returned iterator implements the Python iterator protocol and therefore can only be used in eager mode.

So you need to use `tf.enable_eager_execution()` at the beginning of your script.